# Can I use SOAP UI tool for web testing which do not have any web service

Tags: automation, soapui

I have to use SOAP UI tool for my new project. I do not have any details about its functionality and use. So can I use SOAP UI tool for web site which do not have any web service. Is there any web site(other than www.soapui.org) which gives me manual/sample project for study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use SoapUI to test a simple web site. You are looking for Http TestStep tutorial on their website.

Answer (score 0):

**Live**:

You can make a request from SOAP Ui to a live web service (using tutorial from my answer, from the bottom), for instance:

GeoLookupXML

service to find a city in the Wunderground city database

```
http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=94107
```

where query can be:

- zipcode (US or Canadian)
- city state; city, state
- country

**Locally**:

You can use the example from their site and play with it locally, following this step-by-step tutorial: http://www.soatutorial.net/test-web-services-using-soapui/